# Use a functional component inside Antd's Popover

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I want to customize a button inside Antd Popover, but it seems that passing a React component as children for Antd Popover will make it not even working.

Since I want to use the button and its styles multiple times with different popover, I think making a component makes sense. But Antd doesn't seem to accept it.

Here's my simplified example:

For the button, it's just a bare minimum functional component:

```js
const CustomButton = () => {
  return <button>Custom one</button>
}
```

And the code for the Popover:

```js
<Popover content={content} title="Title" trigger="click">
    <CustomButton />
</Popover>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/ngtrthinh/pen/LYqVWBY)

Expected behavior: Click on the custom button and the popover shows.
Actual behavior: Click on the custom button and the popover does not show.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on `trigger` prop, antd popover clone the children and pass events so it can detect when to open/close the popover. If you select `trigger='click'` then popover will pass `onClick` to children.

Complete List of props based on trigger:

```
click       => ["onClick"]
hover       => ["onMouseEnter", "onPointerEnter", "onMouseLeave", "onPointerLeave"]
focus       => ["onFocus", "onBlur"]
contextMenu => ["onClick", "onContextMenu"]
```

If you console the props of `CustomButton` button, you will see all the props that antd popover pass automatically to children.

You can fix this by distributing all props to button like this:

```
const CustomButton = (props) => {
    return <button {...props}>Custom one</button>;
};
```

This will fix the popover open/close issue. But if you check the console, you will see an error saying: `findDOMNode is deprecated in StrictMode.`.

Popover need to connect with children node using ref inorder to perform some calculation related to position of popover.

To solve this issue, you need to use `forwardRef` and pass the ref to the `button`.

Here's the complete code:

```
import { forwardRef } from 'react';
import { Popover } from 'antd';

const CustomButton = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
    return (
        <button {...props} ref={ref}>
            Custom one
        </button>
    );
});

const content = (
    <div>
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
    </div>
);

const App = () => {
    return (
        <Popover content={content} title='Title' trigger='click'>
            <CustomButton />
        </Popover>
    );
};

export default App;
```